# Openmp not updating

Tags: openmp

I am tryint to write a C (gcc) function that will calculate the maximum of an array of doubles while running across multiple threads. I create an array of size `omp_get_num_threads`, in which I store the local maxima of each thread before finally maximizing this small array. The code is (more or less) the following:

```
int i;
double *local_max;
double A[1e10]; //made up size

#pragma omp parallel
{

#pragma omp master
{
local_max=(double *)calloc(omp_get_num_threads(),sizeof(double));
}

#pragma omp flush  //so that all threads point 
                   //to the correct location of local_max

#pragma omp for

for(i=0;i<1e10;i++){
   if(A[i]>local_max[omp_get_thread_num()])
      local_max[omp_get_thread_num()]=A[i];
}

}

free(local_max);
```

This, however, leads to segfaults, and valgrind complains of the usage of uninitialized variables. Turns out, local_max is not actually updated throughout all threads before they enter the `for` construct. I thought `#pragma omp flush` should do that? If I replace it with `#pragma omp barrier`, everything works fine.

Could someone explain to me what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a barrier to ensure memory allocation has been completed. Memory allocation is a time consuming operation and when your final for loop starts running, local_max is not pointing to a properly allocated space. I modified your code below to demonstrate the behavior.

```
int i;
double *local_max;
omp_set_num_threads(8);
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp master
    {           
        for(int k = 0; k < 999999; k++) {} // Lazy man's sleep function
        cout << "Master start allocating" << endl;
        local_max=(double *)calloc(omp_get_num_threads(),sizeof(double));
        cout << "Master finish allocating" << endl;
    }
#pragma omp flush 
#pragma omp for
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        cout << "for : " << omp_get_thread_num()  << " i: " << i << endl;
    }
}
free(local_max);
getchar();
return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes sense. A follow-up question I have is, when the `flush` construct is encountered by a thread, do all threads synchronize at that same time? Where do they resume execution?

Comment: `flush` is a tricky one and tends to make us think all threads will stop there and synchronize and then all threads continue execution happily. But that is wrong. When a thread encounters `flush`, it synchronizes and resumes the execution. You can play with omp_get_wtime to print execution time and add some random sleep calls in your code to see how it executes. I would recommend you to avoid using `flush` as it adds quite high complexity.

Comment: Does this mean that the other threads do not synchronize at the same time as the one encountering `flush`? What is they are in the process of accessing a variable but in a different part of the parallel construct?

Comment: The openmp documention states that the other parallel threads do not sync at the same time. One last question though--is `flush` performed atomically, i.e. if a variable is being flushed to memory, can other threads try to access it at the same time, leading to race conditions?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution to your problem is to simply replace the `master` construct with a `single` one as it doesn't really matter which thread would make the allocation (unless you are running on a NUMA machine, but then you would also have many other things to worry about):

```c
#pragma omp single
{
   local_max=(double *)calloc(omp_get_num_threads(),sizeof(double));
}
```

The subtle difference between `master` and `single` is that there is an implicit barrier at the end of the `single` while no such barrier exists at the end of `master`. This implicit barrier makes all other threads to wait until the thread that executes the `single` block has made it to the end of the block (unless the `nowait` clause is specified, which removes the implicit barrier). With `master` the barrier must be added explicitly. It is beyond my comprehension why the OpenMP designers made the decision that `master` would not have an implicit barrier like `single` does.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, just move the memory allocation before the #pragma omp parallel. No need for flush, or single, or master.